# Avoiding memory leak while calling retrofit 2

Tags: android, memory-leaks, retrofit, retrofit2

By following [this](https://blog.aritraroy.in/everything-you-need-to-know-about-memory-leaks-in-android-apps-655f191ca859#6bf0) article I found that calling Retrofit enqueue() on onCreate() method may cause a memory leak.

Here is what the article says, doing this:

**Calling Retrofit in the main thread**

```
public class MoviesActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mNoOfMoviesThisWeek;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_movies_activity);
        mNoOfMoviesThisWeek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_of_movies_text_view);

        MoviesRepository repository = ((MoviesApp) getApplication()).getRepository();
        repository.getMoviesThisWeek()
                .enqueue(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Movie>> call,
                                           Response<List<Movie>> response) {
                        int numberOfMovies = response.body().size();
                        mNoOfMoviesThisWeek.setText("No of movies this week: " + String.valueOf(numberOfMovies));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Movie>> call, Throwable t) {
                        // Oops.
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

> Now if this network call runs on a very slow connection and before the call ends, the Activity is rotated or destroyed somehow, then the entire Activity instance will be leaked.

I tried to do the same thing on my app. I called a big content (240 objects) usign enqueue() in onCreate() method. Then while the content was loading I rotated the device multiple times and [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) showed me a memory leak in the Activity as the article said.

Then I tried two approachs to avoid the memory leak:

**First option**

Calling retrofit execute() method on a background thread using static inner class.

**Calling Retrofit in a background thread**

```
private static class RetrofitCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Show>> {
        private WeakReference<TextView> numberOfShows;

        public RetrofitCall(TextView numberOfShows) {
            this.numberOfShows = new WeakReference<>(numberOfShows);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Show> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            List<Show> showList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (!isCancelled()) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(TvMazeService.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                TvMazeService service = retrofit.create(TvMazeService.class);
                try {
                    Response<List<Show>> response = service.getShows().execute();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        showList = response.body();
                    }
                    return showList;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Show> shows) {
            super.onPostExecute(shows);
            TextView textView = numberOfShows.get();
            if (textView != null) {
                String number = String.valueOf(shows.size());
                textView.setText(number);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I tried to get the memory leak using LeakCanary again and it happened that the memory leak was gone.

**Second option**

Using [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

As you can see in the documentation, while using ViewModel I called retrofit asynchronous in the ViewModel class and when the screen is rotated (activity is destroyed) it does not need to load the data again as it remains saved.

This approach also did not give the a memory leak and was the best while talking about memory.

**Questions**

1) Then, using ViewModel to call Retrofit is the best option and it really avoid memory leak?

2) Is there any problem to call retrofit using enqueue() in onCreate() as MoviesActivity does?

3) In this approaches, which one is the best to make a call to authenticate a user?

Comment: This is a good question.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am still searching for this topic, however I got a lot of new information. I will make an answer

Answer (score 1):

1) Using ViewModel in the correct way does not cause memory leaks and is a good option. You can see the [google's video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qlIPTDE274), and also this lecture talking about the [difference between MVP and MVVM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugpC98LcNqA). This second lecture gives a really good explanation about the topic.

2) Calling retrofit enqueue() in onCreate() is a problem and it causes a memory leak. The problem is that the first time you start your activity it calls retrofit, then when you rotate your device, all the activity is destroyed and recreated again. If you rotate the device before the data is loaded completed, retrofit will be called for the second time when onCreate() is called again, and if you keep doing it 10 times, retrofit will be called 10 times, and then you stop rotating the device. The result from the calls will start to come, bzzz :( the result will be displayed 10 times because you called it 10 times. This implies in a huge memory leak. If you implement this approach and use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)  you will see the leak.

3) What is the best approach?

- Using enqueue() method in onCreate() is definitely not good.
- Static inner classes (using AsyncTask) is good, but it does not survive to configuration changes because you need to cancel it in onDestroy(). This is why it does not cause a memory leak because the Task is canceled in onDestroy().
- MVP is a really good approach for making retrofit calls. You can learn more in this [medium article](https://medium.com/cr8resume/working-with-mvp-and-retrofit-2-in-android-b771b8369ec0) and the source code is [here](https://github.com/jazzbpn/MVP-Retrofit-Handdirty).
- Read about the differences between MVP and MVVM as in this [article](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-mvvm-and-mvp/).
- Finally, Google is advising devs to use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) in these scenarios.

You can follow my discussion in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332326/can-i-use-viewmodel-to-send-data-to-the-server/52332687#52332687). Where we are talking about the same subject but while sign in a user to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you will got memory leaks if calling `enqueue()` in `onCreate()` is that the enqueued calls will hold a reference to your activity instance, because the callback instance(anonymous class) passed to it is holding a reference to the enclosing class instance. As long as you cancel it before `onDestroy()`, there won't be a problem.