# Can I use ViewModel to send data to the server?

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit2, viewmodel

Currently, I am using [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to load a list of Shows in my app. Then, I display it in the main screen. It survives to configuration changes and does not provoke memory leaks since ViewModel has this features.

Now I need to do something a bit different. I need to log in a user making a network call to an endpoint using retrofit 2 and rxjava 2, he will type the email and password, and then will be redirected to the MainActivity. Second, I also need to update the user information, he types his new information and then I send to the server.

May I use ViewModel to log in a user or to update user information? If not, what sould I use instead?

**What I need**

This retrofit 2 call should survive to configuration changes, as rotating the screen, and it can not cause memory leak.

**What I tried**

1. Calling retrofit using enqueue() method in the MainActivity. **Obs:** This approach is not good because it puts to much things in the ui class, it provokes memory leaks.
2. Using static inner classes. **Obs:** It does not survive to configuration changes, as I need to cancel the task in onDestroy().
3. MVP seems fine to login a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check google sample project, specifically this class

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvvm-databinding/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/addedittask/AddEditTaskViewModel.java

Usually you would trigger the network operation in the model view, while the code for implementing the network logic is written in a different class (`ApiManager` for example), and then get the results in your ViewModel

- `LoginViewModel` will have an object of some network manager class
- When you click login, the viewmodel will call `networkManager.performLogin()`
- Results are then passed to the viewmodel (RxJava is handy in here).
- In your ViewModel do whatever processing you need when you receive the results

Comment: First of all, thank you for helping! In this google approach, I do not need to extend ViewModel like [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement)?

Comment: You are the one to decide this, MVVP is just an architecture that will tell you how to organize your code and application components. Extending Google's ViewModel class in the view model component of your code will give you more robust control over lifecycle events and take the burden of lifecycle events managements off your shoulder. As a recommendation I would tell you to extend the ViewModel class. I hope this answers your question @SoonSantos

Comment: It helped a lot, I was little bit confusing about this topic. I found this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@saquib3705/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-with-the-help-of-mvvm-dagger-livedata-and-rxjava2-in-67aebefe031d), this is exactly what I was looking for. It is a login using retrofit 2, dagger 2, MVVM and LiveData.